# CEvent MFC replication

Tags: c++, visual-c++

While continuing the series of MFC classes replication (for the knowledgeable) here comes the CEvent class replication:

```
class CEvent {
    HANDLE m_hEvent;
public:

    CEvent(
        BOOL bInitialState,
        BOOL bManualReset)
    {
        LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpEventAttributes = NULL;
        m_hEvent = CreateEvent(lpEventAttributes, 
                                bManualReset,
                                bInitialState,
                                NULL);
    }

    ~CEvent()
    {
        m_hEvent = NULL;
    }

    BOOL SetEvent()
    {
        return ::SetEvent(m_hEvent);
    }

    BOOL ResetEvent()
    {
        return ::ResetEvent(m_hEvent);
    }
    HANDLE GetHandle()
    {
        return m_hEvent;
    }
    operator HANDLE()
    {
        return m_hEvent;
    }
};
```

The code has been edited in consideration with the answer.

Comment: Call ::CloseHandle(m_hEvent) in destructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating named event - _T("Untitled"). Is this on purpose? This way each time CEvent will be created it will refer to the same event - no new one will be created.

Also think of destroying your event in destructor.

Comment: Your information did really solved a lot of problems I had and could not find explanation for.. I must admit I haven't read the CreateEvent documentation carefully. But thank you for your answer.